# git-archive a subdirectory --

Tags: git, subdirectory, git-archive

I'm using git-archive to archive a subdirectory in a git repo, like so:

```
git archive -o ../subarchive.zip HEAD subdir/*
```

However the resulting archive maintains the subdir/ directory structure, i.e. the contents are:

```
subdir/
   whatever.js
   morestuff.js
```

When I actually want whatever.js and morestuff.js at the root of the archive.

How do? Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
git archive -o ../subarchive.zip HEAD:subdir
```

By the way, an easy way to play with the command and see what it will generate is if you use it in this form:

```
git archive --format=tar HEAD:subdir | tar t
git archive --format=tar HEAD subdir | tar t
# ... and so on ...
```

Once you see what you're looking for, you can change the format and use the `-o` flag to actually create the archive.

Comment: Is there any way to do this efficiently for remote repos, e.g. to fetch just one dir/one revision of a gigantic repo that's not practical to clone? I tried `--remote` but it was ridiculously slow.

Comment: It works, great. I was trying to understand which part of the GIT documentation talked about this, but could not. May you elaborate pls?

Comment: @Meglio `git archive --help`, let me know if you cannot find something (and then please be as specific as possible)

Comment: Note that if the current working directory is not the root of the repo, then git will archive from working directory (and descendants) only. To change this, use the `:` notation above - i.e. just `HEAD:`; `HEAD:/` and `HEAD:.` don't work.

Comment: For some reason though, if you use this, it does ignore the `export-ignore` statements in your `.gitattributes`. Even if the file is included in the dir you export and even if you use `--worktree-attributes`.

Comment: Okay, asked a separate question for using this here together with  `.gitattributes` "export-ignore", which did not really work: [How to ignore files/directories in “git archive” and only create an archive of a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804334/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-git-archive-and-only-create-an-archive-of-the)

Answer (score 2):

If you do use `git archive -o ../subarchive.zip HEAD:subdir`, make sure to do it with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023):

"[`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de73a20756e0d938c3098391d011b633ba863530/Documentation/git-archive.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> run from a subdirectory mishandled attributes and paths outside the current directory.

See [commit 92b1dd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92b1dd1b9e6e272c5115d6e37e19a892610a2686) (24 Mar 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit de73a20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de73a20756e0d938c3098391d011b633ba863530), 21 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`archive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92b1dd1b9e6e272c5115d6e37e19a892610a2686): improve support for running in subdirectory
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Cristian Le</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: Matthias Görgens</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> When [`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92b1dd1b9e6e272c5115d6e37e19a892610a2686/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> is started in a subdirectory, it archives its corresponding tree and its child objects, only.
> That is intended.
> It does that by effectively cd'ing into that tree and setting "prefix" to the empty string.
>
> This has unfortunate consequences, though: Attributes are anchored at the root of the repository and `git archive` still applies them to subtrees, causing mismatches.
> And when checking pathspecs it cannot tell the difference between one that doesn't match anthing or one that matches some actual blob outside of the subdirectory, leading to a confusing error message ("`current working directory is untracked`").
>
> Fix that by keeping the "prefix" value and passing it to pathspec and attribute functions, and shortening it using `relative_path()` for paths written to the archive and (if `--verbose` is given) to stdout.
>
> Still reject attempts to archive files outside the current directory, but print a more specific error in that case ("`outside the current directory`").
> Recognizing it requires a full traversal of the subtree for each pathspec, however.
> Allowing them would be easier, but archive entry paths starting with "`../`" can be problematic to extract -- e.g. `bsdtar` skips them by default.