# git archive --format=tar HEAD:mydir/ | tar t -> fatal: current working directory is untracked

Tags: macos, git

I'm trying to archive a folder in my git repository:

```
git archive --format=tar HEAD:mydir/ | tar t
```

However, the error message I'm getting is:

```
fatal: current working directory is untracked
```

The instructions I followed were [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351814/1033422).

My git version is: 2.1.2

A [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22git%20archive%22%20fatal:%20current%20working%20directory%20is%20untracked&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZYlnVcjtLYmssgHknoHgBA#q=%22git%20archive%22%20%22fatal:%20current%20working%20directory%20is%20untracked%22) search only came up with 6 links, all of them a few years old and didn't look relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was:

```
cd $myrepo/mydir
git archive --format=tar  HEAD ./ | tar t
```

Comment: Yeah, I too thought that the path after the colon in `HEAD:` actually is a full path from the git root, turns out it is relative to current location, then... (but only when the colon is not used, as you've posted it)